# C select() goes wrong

Tags: c, sockets, select

I made a small client/server program where the server can handle multiple clients at the same time using the `select()` function. When I run my program everything works fine until I kill a client program, when I kill a client program the server doesn't block at `select()` but it just iterates in the while loop.

When I change the `FD_SETSIZE` in `select(FD_SETSIZE, &copyFds, NULL, NULL, NULL);` to `master_socket + 1` it doesn't block so it works fine.

The GNU library says: The select function checks only the first nfds file descriptors. The usual thing is to pass FD_SETSIZE as the value of this argument. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html

Why do I get this bug? How can I pass in `FD_SETSIZE` and still let the program to block at `select()`?

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
    system("clear");
    printf("***SERVER STARTED***\n");

    char message[125] = "Welcome to my server";
    int master_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fd_set masterFds, copyFds;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(8888);
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof address;
    bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    listen(master_socket, 1);

    FD_ZERO(&masterFds);
    FD_SET(master_socket, &masterFds);

    while (1)
    {
        copyFds = masterFds;

        printf("Monitoring for connections...\n");
        select(FD_SETSIZE, &copyFds, NULL, NULL, NULL); // When a socket wants to connect it's file descriptor gets stored in copyFds

        for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &copyFds))
            {
                if (i == master_socket) // New connection
                {
                    int accepted_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, &addrlen);
                    FD_SET(accepted_socket, &masterFds);
                    printf("[+] New connection accepted\n");

                    write(accepted_socket, message, sizeof(message)); // Send message to client
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not finished yet
                }
            }
        }

        printf("End of while loop\n");
    }
}
```

Client (same headers):

```
int main()
{
    system("clear");
    int clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), x;

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(8888);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));

    char serverResponse[125];
    read(clientSocket, serverResponse, sizeof(serverResponse));
    printf("test: %s\n", serverResponse);

    scanf("%d", &x);

    close(clientSocket);
}
```

Comment: `select()` returns a value. Use it! (connect() read() and write() also return meaningful values)

Comment: How is that gonna help with this situation?

Comment: If a client closes and you do not remove its `fd` from the set, then `select` is going to return immediately.  If you want `select` to block, remove the fd.

Comment: Don't pass `FD_SETSIZE` as the first argument.  That value should be `n + 1` where n is the highest valued fd in the set.  `select` is slow enough already without iterating over a bunch of fd that you don't even care about.

Comment: IOW, you don't want `master_socket + 1`.  You need that value to change depending on the client connections.

Answer (score 1):

If a client closes its connection, you need to remove that fd from the set of descriptors that `select` is watching.  Otherwise, it will return immediately, expecting you to take some action on that `fd`.  In other words, add something like:

```
char buf[1024];                                                            
ssize_t nr = read(i, buf, sizeof buf);                                     
switch( nr ){                                                              
case -1:                                                                   
        perror("read");                                                    
        /* fallthru */                                                     
case 0:                                                                    
        if( close(i) ){                                                    
                perror("close");                                           
        }                                                                  
        puts("Client connection closed");                                  
        FD_CLR(i, masterFds);                                              
        break;                                                             
default:                                                                   
        fwrite(buf, 1, nr, stdout);                                        
        fflush(stdout);                                                    
}
```

in the `else` clause.  (The "Not finished yet" section.)